# Comparing String Values from Strace

Tags: linux, strace

Using strace to compare outputs of two different binaries, I am having trouble determining what the values written actually are.

```
write(3, "g\377\377\377\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096

write(4, "g\377\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
```

The difference from the first to second seems to be \377\377 to \7\0, but what encoding are these using?  These should be decimal values but I do not know how to convert them to compare them.

Comment: Why don't you just try out what strace does? That said, it's probably similar to C code and I believe it is octal.

Comment: This is `octal` notation and `\377` is equal to 0xff in hexadecimal or 11111111 in binary.  And https://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be a better forum for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while UNIX & Linux StackExchange covers general questions.

Comment: Thank you, @tk421.  I should have figured it was octal since chars are bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Strace [`write()` handler](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/io.c#L35) uses a [`printstrn`](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/defs.h#L1044) function, that calls `printstr_ex` function from [util.c](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/util.c) , which calls `string_quote` (also in util.c) which does the printing.

[The function](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/util.c#L579) (by default) prints the data using ASCII characters, then standard C notation of `\r` `\n` and `\b` etc. and then it uses octal values for other non-printable bytes. The string should be parsable by a C compiler, so you can write a simple C program to compare them, ex. `strcmp("g\377\377\377", "g\377\7\0")` will work as expected.

If you want to compare the values, there's also these switches from [man strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html):

> -x
>
> Print all non-ASCII strings in hexadecimal string format.
>
> -xx
>
> Print all strings in hexadecimal string format.